# Android : Run service irrespective of app crash or working

Tags: java, android, crash-reports, android-intentservice, foreground-service

I am working on the functionality to fetch logs of application and upload it to server. We are writing logs into file.

**What i need to do?**

We have used fabric(Currently Firebase crashlystics) for crash reporting. but some time lots of crashes are missed out. so we are unable to track client issue. We decided to implement our own crash reporting tool. We decided to upload logs while starting of the application without any further process. Once app crash then crash report will be write to the file and while app launch next time, that file will be uploaded to server. I don't want to stuck user for such things so i have decided to do this with services. so i need to start service when app is starting and logs should be uploaded to server within service without any hardles. If app crash after next line of the service start, the service should not stop

**What i have tried ?**

I have used service to upload logs to server. I have tried to start foreground service on application class `onCreate()` the service will be on different process and that is working fine as expected. but problem is that, If any crash happen on login activity (first activity) `onCreate()` the foreground service is not starting as expected. Service process is stopped after crash.

**What i want ?**

I want to start foreground service or intent service which upload logs to server. and after uploading logs it will stop. Meanwhile if app crash for some other reason service should not stop and it should complete their task.

**Code**

**Application class**

```
public void onCreate() {
       startLogService()
       // Other code
    }

    private void startLogService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, LogWriteService.class);
       /* if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { // i have tried with this also
            startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
        } else {
            startService(serviceIntent);
        }*/
        bindService(serviceIntent, m_serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

**LogInActivity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_initial_login);
        int i = 10/0; // just for crash test
    }
}
```

**LogSendService class (Intent service)**

```
class LogSendService : IntentService("LogSendService") {

    private val NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345
    internal var allLogFile: File? = null

    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        createAndShowForegroundNotification(this, NOTIFICATION_ID, "We are gathering logs", true)
        writeLogs()
    }

    private fun createAndShowForegroundNotification(mService: Service, notificationId: Int, message: String, isOnGoing: Boolean) {

        val builder = getNotificationBuilder(mService,
                "Log Service", // Channel id
                NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_LOW) //Low importance prevent visual appearance for this notification channel on top
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.home_icon)
                .setContentTitle(mService.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(message)
        if (isOnGoing) {
            builder.setOngoing(true)
        }

        val notification = builder.build()
        mService.startForeground(notificationId, notification)
    }

    private fun writeLogs() {
        try {
            //log write and upload process 
            createAndShowForegroundNotification(this, NOTIFICATION_ID, "success", false)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            createAndShowForegroundNotification(this, NOTIFICATION_ID, e.message!!, false)
        }
        stopForeground(false)
        stopSelf()
    }



    companion object {
        val STATUS_FINISHED = 1

        fun getNotificationBuilder(context: Context, channelId: String, importance: Int): NotificationCompat.Builder {
            val builder: NotificationCompat.Builder
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                prepareChannel(context, channelId, importance)
                builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            } else {
                builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            }
            return builder
        }

        @TargetApi(26)
        private fun prepareChannel(context: Context, id: String, importance: Int) {
            val appName = context.getString(R.string.app_name)
            val description = "Testing Log Service"
            val nm = context.getSystemService(Activity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            if (nm != null) {
                var nChannel: NotificationChannel? = nm.getNotificationChannel(id)

                if (nChannel == null) {
                    nChannel = NotificationChannel(id, appName, importance)
                    nChannel.description = description
                    nm.createNotificationChannel(nChannel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**LogSendService class (Foreground service)**

```
class LogWriteService : Service() {
    private val NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345
    internal var allLogFile: File? = null

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    inner class MyBinder : Binder() {
        val service: LogWriteService
            get() = this@LogWriteService
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        //        startLogService();
        createAndShowForegroundNotification(this, NOTIFICATION_ID, "We are gathering logs", true)
        writeLogs()
    }

    private fun createAndShowForegroundNotification(yourService: Service, notificationId: Int, message: String, isOnGoing: Boolean) {

        val builder = getNotificationBuilder(yourService,
                "Log Service", // Channel id
                NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_LOW) //Low importance prevent visual appearance for this notification channel on top
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.home_icon)
                .setContentTitle(yourService.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(message)
        if (isOnGoing) {
            builder.setOngoing(true)
        }

        val notification = builder.build()
        yourService.startForeground(notificationId, notification)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return Service.START_STICKY
    }

    private fun writeLogs() {
        try {
           //log write and upload
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            createAndShowForegroundNotification(this, NOTIFICATION_ID, e.message!!, false)
        }
        stopForeground(false)
        stopSelf()
    }


    companion object {
        val STATUS_FINISHED = 1

        fun getNotificationBuilder(context: Context, channelId: String, importance: Int): NotificationCompat.Builder {
            val builder: NotificationCompat.Builder
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                prepareChannel(context, channelId, importance)
                builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            } else {
                builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            }
            return builder
        }

        @TargetApi(26)
        private fun prepareChannel(context: Context, id: String, importance: Int) {
            val appName = context.getString(R.string.app_name)
            val description = "Testing Log Service"
            val nm = context.getSystemService(Activity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            if (nm != null) {
                var nChannel: NotificationChannel? = nm.getNotificationChannel(id)

                if (nChannel == null) {
                    nChannel = NotificationChannel(id, appName, importance)
                    nChannel.description = description
                    nm.createNotificationChannel(nChannel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Can some one please suggest solution ? or better way to do that?**

Note : some code is in Java and some in Kotlin

Comment: What do you exactly want? Service should run forever? And use startService() instead of bindService()

Comment: I want to start service for uploading logs to server. it will stop after uploading logs. But condition is that if app crash meanwhile then service should not stop and it should complete that task.

Comment: use startService(). bindService() has scope until binding activity is alive.